Closure properties of fibrations (cartesian functor)
Given fibrations $P$ and $Q$ over the same base and a cartesian functor $F$ as shown below.

I know that when $P$ is discrete, one can easily show that $F$ is a fibration. But this is not true in general when $P$ is not. So if $P$ is not, we take $Q=id_B$ assuming $B$ is nontrivial, then $F$ is right adjoint to $P$, in the sense that $F$ picks a terminal object in each fiber to $P$, so $F$ is not a fibration? But then $F$ to be a fibration, we need each fiber to be 'equivalent' to the single element category $\textbf{1}$.
Which is linked if not precisely condition (2) here Theorem?. I guess it just showing the reverse direction of the proof. So the fibers that are equivalent to $\textbf{1}$ would be of $J$ and $I$.

The critical piece you’re missing is that $F$ restricted to fibers of $Q$ will be fibrations, even when $F$ isn’t in general. It’s late here but I’ll write something up tomorrow.

@AlecRhea So each of these $F_I$ would be fibrations, but then using condition (1) in the Theorem, we can follow the same argument to show that $F$ is a fibration?

Properties of this kind (sometimes called "cancellation") are not really characteristic of fibrations (i.e. some class of morphisms closed under pullback). There is an abstract argument that can be used to establish properties of this kind if the relative diagonal (in this case, $E \to E \times_B E$) is a fibration – a well-known instance is the fact that every continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a proper map.

Lemme A.1.8 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.11312 might be relevant.

@JonathanBeardsley Yes, I will look more into it in detail. Thank you.

As you say, in general $F$ will not be a fibration in the situation outlined above. Despite this, we will have that the fibers of $F$ at each object $I\in{\bf Ob}_B$ $$F_I:Q_I\to P_I$$ will each be fibrations, by the argument given in my other answer to your other linked question. We will not, in general, be able to generalize this argument to show that $F$ is a fibration. I'll see if I can cook up an example of this situation later on today.

I mean if we suppose there is an object $Y \in \mathbf{D}$ and a morphism $f \colon X \to FY$ in $\mathbf{E}$. Since $Q$ is a fibration there is a $Q-$cartesian morphism $\varphi \colon Z \to Y$. Since $F$ is a cartesian functor, it follows that $F(\varphi) \colon FZ \to FY$ is cartesian. It remains to show that $\varphi$ is $F-$cartesian. Suppose $g \colon U \to X$ is a morphism in $E$ and $\psi \colon V \to Y$ is a morphism in $D$ with $F(\psi) = F(\varphi) \circ g$. Then we have $Q(\psi) = Q(\varphi) \circ Pg$ and since $Q$ is a fibration, there exists a unique $\theta \colon V \to Z$ in $D$ with $\psi = \varphi \circ \theta$ and $Q(\theta)=Pg$. Thus $F(\varphi) \circ g = F(\psi) = F(\varphi) \circ F(\theta)$
BUT THEN WE NEED $F(\theta) = g$. How does Conditions (1) and (2) in the Theorem mentioned above ensure this is the question I think, which is not so straightforward.

You seem to be confused in multiple places; first off, in the linked theorem we have that $Q=P\circ F$, which is essential for the theorem to work. Next, we would need an arrow $f:X’\to Q(Y)$ in order to invoke a $Q$-Cartesian arrow $\varphi:X\to Y$ as you do, not an  arrow into $F$ as you have written.

But then you would still need to show that $\varphi$ is $F$-cartesian.
